# Can't connect to a specific WiFi network (Lubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager

I can't seem to connect to a specific WiFi network on my laptop running Lubuntu 16.04 LTS. I had been using this network for months on this laptop, eventually it just stopped working.  I've looked at countless pages attempting to figure out the issue, but with no luck.

I tried using the wireless-info script so I could have more information to provide here, but strangely enough it returned nothing but the "wireless info START" line.

Here's some other info, though:

iwconfig:

```
enp9s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp12s0   IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any 
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=14 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig:

```
enp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:03:73:51:a9:f9  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:95520 (95.5 KB)  TX bytes:95520 (95.5 KB)

wlp12s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:a4:de:48:f9:23  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2076 (2.0 KB)  TX bytes:6612 (6.6 KB)
```

And as requested,
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Wistron NeWeb Corp. DNXA-95 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [185f:30af]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @GAD3R Added it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Add the following line to it:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

Save and reboot

Comment: It still doesn't quite seem to work. Any other ideas?